# read laravel object and get data

Tags: php, css, laravel, object

I am trying to read laravel object and assign  that into a new variable I have no idea to do that please someone help

THIS IS MY FUNCTION

```
public function nextToJumpGrs(CompetitionService $competitionService, CachedEventResourceService $cachedEventResourceService, ConfigurationRepositoryInterface $configurationRepository,MarketRepository $marketTypeRepository)
{

   $nextToJump = $cachedEventResourceService->nextToJump();
   $markets=array();

   $config = $configurationRepository->getConfigByName('sports_settings', true);
   $competitions = $competitionService->getCompetitionsByN2JEventResourcesGrs($nextToJump->slice(0, array_get($config, 'next_to_jump_events')));


  return $competitions;      
   }

}
```

this is what $competitions return

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to read those markets[] and products[]  and assign to another variable  please someone help

Comment: have you tried $products = $competitions->pluck('products'); ?

Answer (score 0):

Just typecast it

```
$array = (array) $competitions;
```

Then loop through it

```
$markets = [];
$products = [];

foreach($array as $item) {
  dump($item['id']);
  dump($item['name']);
  //...
  foreach($item['events'] as $event) {
    dump($event['id']);
    dump($event['name']);
    //...
    $markets[$item['id']][] = $event['markets'];
    foreach($event['markets'] as $market) {
      dump($market['id']);
      dump($market['name']);
      dump($market['line']);
      //...
    }
    $products[$item['id']][] = $event['products'];
    foreach($event['products'] as $product) {
      dump($product['product_id']);
      dump($product['bet_type']);
      dump($product['product_code']);
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: not working it's says Undefined index: id  when i do this dump($item['id']);

Comment: Could you dump($item) and paste it here ?

Comment: $config = $configurationRepository->getConfigByName('sports_settings', true);
       $competitions = $competitionService->getCompetitionsByN2JEventResourcesGrs($nextToJump->slice(0, array_get($config, 'next_to_jump_events')));
       
       $array = (array) $competitions;

     foreach($array as $item) {
   dump($item['id']);
  
}